# ES6 override class method in runtime

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a base class from which another class inherits
However, before instantiating the child class, I need to change one of the methods, based on the method of another class.

The problem is that the super call fails, with an error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).invoke is not a function
```

Below is a simplified version of my issue.

```
class Base{
        invoke(){
            console.log('base')
        }
    }

    class Child extends Base{
        invoke(){
            super.invoke();
            console.log('child')
        }
    }

    class Test{

        invoke(){
            super.invoke();
            console.log('test')
        }
    }

    Child.prototype.invoke = Test.prototype.invoke;
    const t = new Child;
    t.invoke();
```

Note: I do not want Child to inherit from Test.

I want to override Child's invoke, to use the one from Test.

I believed that it would be straight forward, but this super call is causing issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting `Test.prototype.invoke` to do? `Test` does not have a `super` class

Comment: You are right. Is there any way for the above scenario to work? I know javascript is pretty flexible, but everything I tried did not work

Comment: It depends. What code are you expecting the `super.invoke()` within `Test` to call?

Comment: Ideally, since it will override Child's invoke, to call Base's invoke. Just as Child's would

Comment: As I said in my post, I do not want Test to extend Base. Just to override Child.invoke, while maintaining the inheritance. Test needs to be independent.

Comment: What should your output look like according to your simplified example? What sequence of statements are you hoping for?

Comment: @Icepickle: in the console, you should first see base and then test.

Comment: Thomas, I think you could make a higher order function that integrates the `Test` with the `Child` class, I am however unsure if your test means to test the `Base` class or the `Child` class, from the follow up of statements, I would believe you wish to test the `Base` class. Are you looking for something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/sj2b5dg1/)?

Comment: Icepickle, thanks for the feedback. However, I need Test to completely override Child's method. The higher order function invokes it. Basically, I need to print base and then test

Comment: Can I ask then why Child is needed? It seems you are rather looking at replacing child ;) Maybe you could just call the Base prototype invoke with the this context? A bit like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sj2b5dg1/2/

Comment: Let me provide some context. The app is a React app bundled with webpack running as a dekstop app with Electron. There is a also a CMS where someone can provide JS code that will be retrieved from the app and override existing methods. So Child in this case represents a bundled class (which inherits from a base one). Test represents the code retrieved from the CMS. Now the example you provided works just fine, but because we have webpack and babel doing their thing, I cannot use Base.prototype.invoke.call( this ), because Base is not resolved in the downloaded code.

Comment: Apart from that your solution is great. Looking forward for the day we will not need Babel/Webpack :)

Comment: Alright, but doesn't that mean, you don't really have invoke either? If it's minified? There is another option to use a Proxy, to catch the real call, but if you don't know the method to be overwritten, I think it doesn't really make it easier either ;)

Comment: Don't really get what you mean by "you don't really have invoke either". invoke exists in the bundled class and needs to be overridden. I believe I am hitting a dead end with this approach and need to consider another solution. Appreciate the help however

Comment: I mean if it is minified, then there is no real `invoke` method, but rather something like `i` :)

Comment: Right on this one too.